# I have to put sorted list and sorted array into dictionary

Tags: arrays, list, sorting, python-2.7

How do I put values from a sorted list and array into a dictionary and determine how many time numbers repeat themselves? This is my code so far.

```
from numpy import *
from random import *

lista=[]
for x in range(0,20):
    broj=input("Unesi %d broj>>" % (x+1))
    lista.append(broj)
print"Nesortirana lista>>",lista

while True:
    ne=False
    for b in range(0,len(lista)-1):
        if lista[b] > lista[b+1]:
        pomocna=lista[b]
        lista[b]=lista[b+1]
        lista[b+1]=pomocna
        ne=True
if ne == False:
    break
print "Sortirana lista",lista

velicina_polja = 10
polje = array(velicina_polja * [0])
for i in range(0, velicina_polja):
    polje[i] = randrange(1, 11)

print "Nesortirano polje:", polje

ima_promjene = True

while ima_promjene:
    ima_promjene = False
    for i in range(0, velicina_polja - 1):
        if polje[i] > polje[i + 1]:
            polje[i], polje[i + 1] = polje[i + 1], polje[i]
            ima_promjene = True

print "Sortirano polje:", polje
```

Comment: I realize that English is probably not your first language, but can you try to explain a bit more what you are trying to do and what is going wrong? It seems that you're sorting two data structures, but I don't understand what you need to do with a dictionary.

Comment: my taks is to make program.first i nedd to input 20 number in list and sort it.Then I nedd 10 random numbers in array and sort than.For last step of program I nedd create a dictionary in which i must put all numbers from list and array and then determine how often this particular number is in array and list together.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_list = [ 1, 2, 3, 3]
    my_dict = {}

    for item in my_list:
        my_dict[item] = my_dict.get(item, 0) + 1
    for key in my_dict.keys():
        print key, ":", my_dict[key]
```

It adds one to the count for a given key. If the key is not already in the dictionary, it assumes a value of zero and then increments that.
So the above example prints:

```
1 : 1
2 : 1
3 : 2
```